# Printing a Report having Covering & Footer as Sub Reports in processing screen

Tags: acumatica

I have created a custom report which is having a covering letter as subreport called in report header and a summary report called in the report footer. This works fine when called in an action menu to print a single report.

I have designed a processing screen similar to Sales Order Print/Email processing and while print more than one document, the covering letter prints once and main report print for all the selected document and summary report prints for the last document.

```
public PXAction<SOOrder> printreport;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Print Production Report", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
    [PXButton(SpecialType = PXSpecialButtonType.ReportsFolder)]
    protected virtual IEnumerable PrintReport(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
        List<SOOrder> list = adapter.Get<SOOrder>().ToList();
        if (list.Count > 0)
        {
            string reportID = "PS642000";
            Base.Save.Press();
            Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            string actualReportID = null;

            PXReportRequiredException ex = null;
            Dictionary<PX.SM.PrintSettings, PXReportRequiredException> reportsToPrint = new Dictionary<PX.SM.PrintSettings, PXReportRequiredException>();

            foreach (SOOrder order in list)
            {
                PSSOOrderExtNV extNV = Base.Document.Cache.GetExtension<PSSOOrderExtNV>(order);
                if (extNV.UsrIsScreenPrint != true)
                    continue;
                parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                parameters["SOOrder.OrderType"] = order.OrderType;
                parameters["SOOrder.OrderNbr"] = order.OrderNbr;

                object cstmr = PXSelectorAttribute.Select<SOOrder.customerID>(Base.Document.Cache, order);
                actualReportID = new NotificationUtility(Base).SearchReport(SONotificationSource.Customer, cstmr, reportID, order.BranchID);
                ex = PXReportRequiredException.CombineReport(ex, actualReportID, parameters);

                reportsToPrint = PX.SM.SMPrintJobMaint.AssignPrintJobToPrinter(reportsToPrint, parameters, adapter, new NotificationUtility(Base).SearchPrinter, SONotificationSource.Customer, reportID, actualReportID, order.BranchID);
            }

            if (ex != null)
            {
                PX.SM.SMPrintJobMaint.CreatePrintJobGroups(reportsToPrint);

                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

How to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried and did not work. Now I have removed the sub report and executing separately in the sequence to archive the required result.

```
    public PXAction<SOOrder> screenprintreport;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Screen Print Production Report", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
    [PXButton(SpecialType = PXSpecialButtonType.ReportsFolder)]
    protected virtual IEnumerable screenPrintReport(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
        List<SOOrder> list = adapter.Get<SOOrder>().ToList();
        if (list.Count > 0)
        {
            string creportID = "SO641010";
            string reportID = "PS642000";
            Base.Save.Press();
            Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            string actualReportID = null;

            PXReportRequiredException ex = null;
            Dictionary<PX.SM.PrintSettings, PXReportRequiredException> reportsToPrint = new Dictionary<PX.SM.PrintSettings, PXReportRequiredException>();

            foreach (SOOrder order in list)
            {
                PSSOOrderExtNV extNV = Base.Document.Cache.GetExtension<PSSOOrderExtNV>(order);
                if (extNV.UsrIsScreenPrint != true)
                    continue;
                parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                parameters["SOOrder.OrderType"] = order.OrderType;
                parameters["SOOrder.OrderNbr"] = order.OrderNbr;

                object cstmr = PXSelectorAttribute.Select<SOOrder.customerID>(Base.Document.Cache, order);
                actualReportID = new NotificationUtility(Base).SearchReport(SONotificationSource.Customer, cstmr, creportID, order.BranchID);
                ex = PXReportRequiredException.CombineReport(ex, actualReportID, parameters);

                reportsToPrint = PX.SM.SMPrintJobMaint.AssignPrintJobToPrinter(reportsToPrint, parameters, adapter, new NotificationUtility(Base).SearchPrinter, SONotificationSource.Customer, creportID, actualReportID, order.BranchID);
                actualReportID = null;
                actualReportID = new NotificationUtility(Base).SearchReport(SONotificationSource.Customer, cstmr, reportID, order.BranchID);
                ex = PXReportRequiredException.CombineReport(ex, actualReportID, parameters);

                reportsToPrint = PX.SM.SMPrintJobMaint.AssignPrintJobToPrinter(reportsToPrint, parameters, adapter, new NotificationUtility(Base).SearchPrinter, SONotificationSource.Customer, reportID, actualReportID, order.BranchID);


            }

            if (ex != null)
            {
                PX.SM.SMPrintJobMaint.CreatePrintJobGroups(reportsToPrint);

                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```